# Redirect to NEW Action with prefilled values in EasyAdmin 3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

I am currently trying to add a Clone action to my EmployeeCrudController.
The action should redirect to the Action::NEW view and have some prefilled values.
However I can't figure out how to prefill this form.

Here is where how I define my action within the EmployeeCrudController:

```
  public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
  {
    $cloneAction = Action::new('Clone', '')
        ->setIcon('fas fa-clone')
        ->linkToCrudAction('cloneAction');

    return $actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $cloneAction);
  }
```

And this is how my cloneAction looks like, which currently redirects to the Action::NEW as expected but without prefilled values:

```
 public function cloneAction(AdminContext  $context): RedirectResponse
 {
    $id     = $context->getRequest()->query->get('entityId');
    $entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Employee::class)->find($id);

    $clone = new Employee();
    $entity->copyProperties($clone);
    $clone->setFirstname('');
    $clone->setLastname('');
    $clone->setEmail('');

    $routeBuilder = $this->get(CrudUrlGenerator::class);
    $url = $routeBuilder->build([
            'Employee_lastname' => 'test',
            'Employee[teamMembershipts][]' => $clone->getTeamMemberships(),

        ])
        ->setController(EmployeeCrudController::class)
        ->setAction(Action::NEW)
        ->generateUrl()
    ;

    return $this->redirect($url);
 }
```

Comment: Hello, did you found a solution ? I've exactly the same problem

Comment: @eronn no, i just went back to easyadmin 1

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of a field in easyAdmin using the option [data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data).

```
$builder->add('Employee_lastname', null, ['data' => $clone->getTeamMemberships()]);
```

If your field has multiple options, you can use the [choices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices) and [choices_value](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-value).

Comment: This actually doesen't work in this case. You don't have access to a $builder here.

Answer (score 0):

Example how i do that:

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
    $actions =  parent::configureActions($actions);

    ...

    $createRegistration = Action::new('createRegistration', 'Create registration')
        ->linkToUrl(function ($entity) {
            return $this->container->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class)
                ->setController(RegistrationCrudController::class)
                ->set('form_field_event_id', $entity->getId())
                ->setAction(Action::NEW)
                ->generateUrl();
        })
    ;

    ...

    return $actions;
}


public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {

    ...

    $eventFormTypeOptions = [];
    if($pageName === Crud::PAGE_NEW && $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('form_field_event_id')){
        $eventFormTypeOptions['data'] = $this->eventRepository->find($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->get('form_field_event_id'));
    }
    yield AssociationField::new('event')
        ->setFormTypeOptions($eventFormTypeOptions);

    ...

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).